# Android app with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, apk

I don't know how to connect index.htm to android app in android studio. 
Several guides on youtube have simillar, almost the same syntax i used and none of them worked, giving me this error. Maybe someone here can help me please :)
Error is in this screenshot : http://prntscr.com/ea48b1

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you have a webview with id **webView** inside the layout file activity_main

and you have correctly place your html file in asset/www folder with name "index.html"